# Are Ruby arrays true arrays?

Tags: ruby, arrays

I understand that Ruby arrays are both dynamically allocated *and* dynamically resized; however, I can't seem to find any clear information on whether they are *true* arrays; i.e. they are contiguous in memory (more specifically, the references they hold are contiguous in memory).

My assumption would be that increasing the size of a Ruby array entails reallocation of the entire array to a larger contiguous memory block where required.

Is this correct, or is "array" a misnomer in this instance?

Comment: Maybe reading the source code in [`array.c`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/array.c) will shed some light?

Comment: The information an array holds about its elements is only their object ids.

Comment: http://ruby-hacking-guide.github.io/object.html and go to `struct RArray` section. Well, it's for old Ruby but if you are going to read source this may help you.

Comment: See also [Ruby Under a Microscope](http://patshaughnessy.net/ruby-under-a-microscope) (payware) by Pat Shaughnessy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Ruby Language Specification does not prescribe any particular memory representation for `Array` objects (or *any* object, actually). That would be too restricting for the implementors. In fact, it doesn't even prescribe that objects have to live in memory *at all*, which makes possible implementations like MagLev where the Object Memory is a distributed on-disk OO database instead of RAM.

The Ruby Language Specification also does not prescribe any particular performance characteristics for any methods of the `Array` class.

*However*, Ruby programmers have come to expect certain performance guarantees from certain `Array` methods (and any implementation that doesn't meet those guarantees will simply be ignored by the community), e.g.

- `Array#[]` shall have a worst-case step complexity of O(#of items sliced)
- `Array#<<` shall have a worst-case step complexity of O(n) and an amortized worst-case step complexity of O(1)
- … and so on.

Basically, the typical performance guarantees you would expect from a dynamic array.

This more or less means that the only way to meet those performance guarantees is that the implementation must use contiguous storage and exponential resizing.

Comment: Pretty much exactly the kind of answer I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: "The Ruby Language Specification" - that's interesting. I have never heard about that. I have read that Ruby doesn't have the specification. As I may be wrong (or my informations are outdated), could you provide link to the specification?

Comment: @DarekNędza: http://ISO.Org/iso/iso_catalogue/catalogue_tc/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=59579

Answer (score 10):

Having reviewed the [source](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/array.c) and the [article](http://ruby-hacking-guide.github.io/object.html) referenced by Darek in the comments, I can confirm that Ruby's arrays are, indeed, genuine arrays and consist of contiguous memory blocks, where the element at a given index can be accessed in O(1) time.

It seems that Ruby over-allocates arrays to improve the efficiency of `push` and similar operations; however, when the capacity of the array is exceeded, the array is automatically `realloc`ated at a larger size.

This is a fairly important distinction that seems to be largely neglected, so hopefully this information will be useful to others searching for similar enlightenment.

Comment: Overallocating, and in particular exponential overallocating is required to get O(1) amortized worst-case step complexity for append. That's the usual way to implement dynamic arrays. And not exponentially resizing is a common mistake resulting in poor performance.